# Connection Refused in elixir on windows7

Tags: javascript, websocket, elixir

WebSocket Connection to `ws://localhost:4000/phoenix/live_reload/socket/websocket?vsn=2.0.0` failed:

> Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

This error will poped up always when I try to run a chat application in `Elixir` by using `Phoenix Framework`.
I used Phoenix 1.3.0 and Elixir 1.5.1

Comment: Just in case: there is nothing else running on the this port ?